# Are there anything like Adwords Date Ranger/Picker avaible?

Tags: jquery, date

Do anybody know if there is a jquery script that can do the same the way Adwords Date Range/picker is?

I know this one, but the way you can set a custom date range is really messed. There should be some empty input instead, for examples, what if i want to go 4 years back. Then i have to presh backwards 4*12 = 48 click. For just selecting 4 years.
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

But i really like that it has preset.

This is also really good, but it missed again the present and how much trouble it is selecting 4 years ago.
http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

That would be so nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add month and year drop down menus with the jQuery UI plug in:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant, you can check out [Date Ranger](https://github.com/n0nick/dateranger) ([Demo page](http://n0nick.github.com/dateranger/)) I worked on a few months ago. It works in conjunction with an existing date picker widget (i.e. jQuery UI's).

It's pretty easy to customize and add more presets if needed.